# jquery attr problem

Tags: jquery, image, attr

I am trying to upload a picture using jquery. and the upload should be done with no page refresh.

the code:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
                    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),

        button: $('#account #picture .header')[0],
        action: '<?= Route::url('Account Upload Avatar'); ?>',
        allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'],
        onSubmit: function()
        {

        },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, avatar)
        {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#picture img').attr('src', responseJSON + '?' + (new Date).getTime());
        }
    });
```

and where i have the picture upload:

```
        <div id="picture">
        <div class="header">
            Schimba-ti poza
        </div>

    <img src="<?= $image->avatar_url ?>"></img>
    </div>
```

the problem is: 
the upload is done right, but i can see the new picture only if i refresh the page. otherwise, when i upload a new picture, the old one dissapears, and instead appears an image broken icon, and if i inspect the element, i see: `<img id="picture" src="undefined?1308840720252">` so i get that undefined.. and i guess it is because that attr.
i am using jquery 1.6.1
any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: what does a console.log(avatar) give you?

Comment: I think you should use prop instead of attr

Comment: Can you console.log avatar.url in onComplete to see its value?

Comment: doesn;t work with prop either

Comment: @Karolis. `src` is an attribute not a property

Comment: @Neal src is both: an attribute of DOM and a property of Image object.

Comment: ReferenceError: avatar is not defined

Comment: @Karolis -- read the chart on this site http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/ to see what should be used with `prop` and what with `attr`

Comment: @Neal hm... a little confusing jQuery approach. I thouhgt jQuery attributes are attributes of DOM, and jQuery properties are properties of JavaScript objects. But they made some kind of a mix :) Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Karolis, that is how the new `prop()` function works... (you can see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr for the debate)

Comment: @Neal Yeah, it was interesting. Most of the information was know to me. But I still don't understand why they didn't implemented such properties like `href` and `src` :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is a **`defined`** variable at `avatar.url` <-- which could be the cause of the issue

Comment: yes, i receive in the console an error: ReferenceError: avatar is not defined but i cannot really understand it. how can i define the variable at avatar.url? thanks!

Comment: @dana -- this is for `avatar` or `avatar.url`?

Comment: also for avatar.url:  console.log(avatar.url)
and console.log(avatar)

Comment: @dana you tried @Alnitak's suggestion of `console.log(avatar);`?

Comment: @dana try using `responseJSON` as it is defined in the spec instead of `avatar`

Comment: not working. now, i get  no broken image and no undefined, but still i have to refresh the page for the image to change

Comment: @dana what about when u do `console.log(responseJSON);`?

Comment: @dana are you sure your server response has a JSON value in it?

Comment: ReferenceError: responseJSON is not defined

Comment: though i have now request.JSON instead on avatar

Comment: @dana... can you updat eyour question (by appending an update) to show what your code looks like surrently and what **ALL** the issues and nonissues are?

Comment: i have edited it, though i have not got much to edit. i just replaced the avatar.url with the responseJSON. now it doesn;t even try to upload me the picture instantly, so it doesn;t show the broken image. not it shows me the old one after upload, until i am refreshing the page.

Comment: @dana, append means **add on** not change....   make the function: `onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON)`

Comment: now it shows me the broken image instantly after upload again, and on image analysis i have <img src="[object Object]?1308843019623"> instead of undefined

Comment: same... ReferenceError: responseJSON is not defined

Comment: @dana. where are u putting that console.log? can you put up your code on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: i try using jsfiddle but i'm not quite used to it

Comment: @dana... i know what you are trying...  goto http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript might be able to help you better over there

Answer (score 0):

Your server side could should be returning valid JSON which will be parsed and sent to `onComplete` as the third function parameter.

If the JSON can't be received you'll receive an empty object.

Do:

```
console.log(avatar);
```

inside the callback to check what's actually in that third parameter.

Comment: i have commented above. it is not defined(the avatar)

Comment: which suggests that you're not sending valid JSON.  Next please show us what your server-side script is outputing.